# How do I check for slightly off white colour on an IPS monitor?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, color-management

Hey everyone I recently took some shot of a model wearing my products against a white roll of paper. They turned out great but of course I had to do adjustments. Anyways the issue I'm having is the image looks great but I'm pasting it on top of a pure white canvas in photoshop - the background of the image looks white and I can't tell its off white on my IPS screen.

If I go on my laptop and look at it at normally it is slightly discolored but looking at it at an angle I can see that the white in the picture is clearly off.

My question is how do I edit the picture so I can see these blemishes on a higher quality screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you have photographed the products against a white background.  I guess you're extracting the product from that background and pasting onto a true RGB(255,255,255) pure white background in photoshop.  I think what you're saying is that you have some areas from the original background which isn't pure white, and those don't blend in with the pure white background?

If so, and the original has a color tint, and you want it to be pure white, then before extracting the product from the original background, use a curves adjustment layer, and use the white eyedropper and select part of the background and that should correct the color cast, and will also bring that part of the background close to pure white so it matches the background you're pasting on.

Answering your question more directly I think, once you have the image pasted on the pure white background, if you want to check it, I would use a levels adjustment layer.  Move the midtone (middle) slider almost all the way to the right.  This will increase contrast in the lightest tones and show you places where you don't have matching whites.  You could also use a threshhold adjustment layer.  Find spots, paint them over with a white brush or mask them off, then throw away the levels/threshhold layer when you're done.

I hope I've understood the question.  If not, clarify :)

Comment: thanks! I ended up making another layer with an adjusted curve to see the tinted areas and air brushed it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that a white roll of paper isn't actually white. It's kind of a very light grey yellow colour. There's very few things in the real world that are actually white.

So in some ways there's always an adjustment to be made, your camera does some when it takes the photo as it treats white and nearly white colours as the same, your computer screen does the same and your software does it's best to accomodate all these adjustments.

So with all production work a bit of practice and experimentation is required to get the result you want. In similar situations I have simply cut out or airbrushed over the offending bits, but there are countless ways to get to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Robin, I understand that what the camera sees isn't exactly white but my issue was that I can't see this off color on my IPS screen.